# Storage Folder is not found in DB - TYPO3 Extension development

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions

I'm new to extension development.
I have created a job application extension using the extension builder.
the data is saving to DB successfully but not to the storage folder. I have linked the folder from the backend.
Screenshots: https://nimb.ws/wuIvTY , https://nimb.ws/pLaoJd

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason could be in the generated code of the extension builder. Inside the `setup.txt` or `setup.typoscript`the ExtBuilder place code like:

```
plugin.tx_myExt_myPlugin {
    view {
        templateRootPaths.0 = EXT:myExt/Resources/Private/Templates/
        templateRootPaths.1 = {$plugin.tx_myExt_myPlugin.view.templateRootPath}
        partialRootPaths.0 = EXT:myExt/Resources/Private/Partials/
        partialRootPaths.1 = {$plugin.tx_myExt_myPlugin.view.partialRootPath}
        layoutRootPaths.0 = EXT:myExt/Resources/Private/Layouts/
        layoutRootPaths.1 = {$plugin.tx_myExt_myPlugin.view.layoutRootPath}
    }
    persistence {
        storagePid = {$plugin.tx_myExt_myPlugin.persistence.storagePid}
        #recursive = 1
    }
    features {
        #skipDefaultArguments = 1
        # if set to 1, the enable fields are ignored in BE context
        ignoreAllEnableFieldsInBe = 0
        # Should be on by default, but can be disabled if all action in the plugin are uncached
        requireCHashArgumentForActionArguments = 1
    }
    mvc {
        #callDefaultActionIfActionCantBeResolved = 1
    }
}
```

The problem here is the line with the storagePid which is not setted. Removing this line would only temporary work until you regenerate the plugin so what you could do is to add the following line under the ExtBuilder Marker:

```
## EXTENSION BUILDER DEFAULTS END TOKEN - Everything BEFORE this line is overwritten with the defaults of the extension builder

plugin.tx_myExt_myPlugin.persistence >
```

After that your controller should use the storage which you setted him in the plugin configuration.